# Decode quoted-printable email strings in Rust (Like =?UTF-8?Q??=D1=81_=D0)

Tags: email, utf-8, rust, mime, quoted-printable

Is there any good crate which can decode quoted-printable strings in mail subjects, senders and etc?

I just found mini crate named [quoted_printable](https://crates.io/crates/quoted_printable). But this not helped a lot. For example from string like

> =?utf-8?Q?=D0=A1=D0=B1=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81_=D0=BF=D0=B0?= =?utf-8?Q?=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=8F_=D0=BD=D0=B0_=D1=81=D0=B0=D0=B9=D1=82?= =?utf-8?Q?=D0=B5?=

i gain

> "=?utf-8?Q?Сброс_па?= =?utf-8?Q?роля_на_сайт?= =?utf-8?Q?е?="

Is there any crate which can give me good string without **=?utf-8?Q?** and so on?

Comment: Did you try filling a bug report in the "quoted_printable" github repository? What's the expected result for your input?

Comment: @SirDarius it must look like "Сброс пароля на сайт", no its not problem of library, its another encoding - see answer below by Lanely

Answer (score 0):

this is rfc2047-encoded email header. I see 2 crates which (in theory) should be able to decode it: [email](https://crates.io/crates/email) and [rustyknife](https://crates.io/crates/rustyknife). Maybe there is something else, look for "email" and "mime" on crates.io

Comment: Ok, will try and write after - i saw that rfc and this crates too)